# Cannot run a MahaSecure banking app in Ubuntu 20.10 as earier versions of ubuntu?

Tags: 20.10

I have upgraded system to Ubuntu 20.10

but  Mahasecure net banking app is not getting open even there has been a shortcut generated on

desktop after installation .

in earlier ubuntu 19.10  Mahasecure net banking app was working well.
.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what Mahasecure is, but I suspect that the problem is with `qt`.

Try to install `qt4`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qt4-default
sudo apt install qt5-default
```

Comment: hello , I tried to run qt4 ,but it does not released date Ubuntu 20.10